# C# Cannot add or modify List in WCF

Tags: c#, list, wcf

I am using example code from a tutorial on Creating a WCF Service and it only half works.  Adding to the List works when it's hard-coded and retrieving the List works.  However, using a routine to Add or modify the List does not work.  Here is the code:
BookData.cs

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace BookServicesV2
{
    [DataContract]

    public class BookData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

BookService.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


    namespace BookServicesV2
    {
        // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class BookService : IBookService
    {
        private List<BookData> _books;

        private BookService()
        {
            _books = new List<BookData>();

            var book = new BookData { BookID = 1, Author = "Shakespeare", Title = "To Be or Not To Be", Price = 1.49M };
            _books.Add(book);

            book = new BookData { BookID = 2, Author = "Mark Twain", Title = "Not Dead Yet", Price = 3.50M };
            _books.Add(book);
        }

        #region IBookService Members

        public void AddBook(BookData book)
        {
            if (book != null) _books.Add(book);
        }

        public void UpdatePrices(decimal increaseAmmount)
        {
            foreach (var book in _books)
            {
                book.Price += increaseAmmount;
            }
        }

        public List<BookData> GetBooks()
        {
            return _books;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

When I launch the WCF Test Client, GetBooks retrieves the two hard-coded books.  When I use AddBook or UpdatePrices and then GetBooks, nothing has changed.  I'm basically learning c# and WCF on the fly, so I am completely stumped.  Thanks!

Comment: have you debugged your add and update methods to see if they're actually being hit by the client and whether or not the book coming into the method is null?

Comment: It's been a while I used WCF myself, but I would guess that the issue is that you get a new instance of your `BookService` each time you call `GetBooks`. You need to make sure that your list is persisted, e.g. in a database.

Comment: .. or just make sure your scope is modified..

Comment: as @DirkVollmar pointed, each call creates a new instance of *_books* variable. You define it as static for your example, like this: `private static List<BookData> _books`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the service behavior of your BookService.cs.

```
 [ServiceBehavior(  ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
                   InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single )]
public class BookService : IBookService{...}
```

This will change it to a singleton object. In other words, only 1 instance of your service is created.

You can also use InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession as well. That means an object is created and maintained for each connection. If you close the connection and then re-connect you would have a new instance but you would be dealing with the same instance for each subsequent call you made to the service (assuming you don't close/reconnect).

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I still don't know where / how they set it up in the tutorial, but it now works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Wcf by default create a new instance at each call. Every time you call the service on client, your list will allways have the two hardcoded books.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you creating a new `BookService` For each Wcf request. You can change the `InstanceContextMode` to `Single` in your config or you can do it programatically so that just one instance is called for all requests. You can google out how to set this behaviour